# Show a specific page based on GPS coordinates?

Tags: javascript, php, android, html, gps

I want to make a script that only shows a page if the user is within 10 meters or so of a certain gps location, maybe using the same technique for showing a certain page based on the users city or country like in this guide here http://www.userlocation.com/pcode

Would anyone know how to make it?

So if the user is not within range of the gps coordinate it will show an access denied page..

Comment: Try using LocationManager to get current location.
Useful link: http://www.rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/01/get-current-location-coordinates-city.html

Comment: I'm using the script below to getLocation and have the coordinates sent to google speadsheet e.g <body onload="getLocation()">

Comment: <script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position)
{
lat=position.coords.latitude;
lon=position.coords.longitude;
document.getElementById("entry_677679850").value=lat;
document.getElementById("entry_1140010409").value=lon; 
return true; 
}</script>

Comment: So I am able to get their location, I just need it to only show a page if they are within a 10-40 meter radius of a certain gps coordinate